# dynamic import with interpolated string

Tags: parceljs

I'm trying out parcel in a hobby project, having worked with create-react-app (i.e. webpack) before. I have had a great experience with dynamic imports of the following sort:

```
const Page = React.lazy(() => import(`./${page}`));
```

This is in a wrapper component that takes care of the suspense etc. and gets `page` as a prop (always a literal string, no variable/expression. not sure if that makes a difference).

With webpack this works wonderfully, even though I'm not sure how. Each such page I hit in the app gets loaded the first time, then its available instantly. I understand this is quite hard for the bundler to figure out, but yeah, it works.

When I try the same with parcel, it still builds but fails at runtime. If I dynamically import e.g. `'./SomePage'`, that is exactly what is requested from the server (`GET /SomePage`), which of course serves index.html. This happens both on the dev server and with a build. The build also only produces one `.js` file, so it doesn't split at all.

Is this even possible with parcel to import like this? Am I missing some configuration (don't have any at the moment)?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an unfix bug in webpack that dynamic import with interpolation will be having issue due to they are not able to pinpoint the exact file path.

[Source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-451034292)

> Webpack will collects all the dependencies, then check the import statement, parse the params to a reg statement, like this:
>
> `import('./app'+path+'/util') => /^\.\/app.*\/util$/`
>
> Webpack look for modules that meet the criteria based on reg. So if the param is a variable, Webpack will use the wrong reg statement to look for modules, in other words, will look for modules globally.

Try adding an empty string and append the interpolation might help you on this.

```js
const Page = React.lazy(() => import("" + `./${page}`));
```

Comment: I'm not having issues with webpack, just mentioned that because its working there. Its *parcel* that doesn't understand what I want.

Comment: sorry, my apologies for answering wrongly